# Javascript conditional in template string

Tags: javascript, template-strings

Is there a way to do conditional within a template string?

For example:

```
let x, y;

x = ...
y = ...

let templateString = `${x} ${y}`;
```

I don't want the space in the template string after x to be output if y is undefined. How would I achieve that with template string?

Is this the only way to do it?

```
 let templateString = `${x}${y ? ' ' + y : ''}`;
```

Comment: `let templateString = y ? \`${x} ${y}\` : \`${x}\`;`

Comment: in this case you might as well replace ``${x}`` with just x, or String(x) to force it to be a string

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What about

```
let x,y;

const templateString = [x,y].filter(a => a).join(' ');
```

What it does that it first puts your properties into an array [].

Then it filters the undefined items.

The last it creates a string of the array, by using `join` with a space.

This way either `x` or `y` can be undefined.

Comment: Nice functional approach

Answer (score 13):

It would look easier to read if you don't add the logic in the template:

```
let templateString = y ? `${x} ${y}` : `${x}`;
```

Answer (score 9):

It's probably overkill for this small example, butTagged template functions provide a nice general solution that allow an amazing amount of flexibility while keeping your template strings clean. For example here's one that will remove text preceding an undefined variable in general:

```js
function f(str ,...variables){
  return variables.reduce((res, v, i) => v ? res + str[i] + v: res, '')
}
let x, y, z;

x = "test"
y = "test2"

// both defined
console.log(f`${x} + ${y}`)

// only one:
console.log(f`${x} + ${z}`)

// random text:
console.log(f`${x} with ${z} and ${y}`)
```

Since it passes everything to a function, you can do almost any logic you want while still having readable strings. There's some documentation about halfway down the [MDN Page on template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: @baklazan the function is passed an array of strings `str` which represent the text part of the template and an argument for variable (stored in `variables`) in the template. The `reduce` is looping through the variables and building up a string, by testing whether the variable is truthy. If it is it adds the corresponding string and variable to the returned string.

Answer (score 7):

technically you can nest these template strings, its not pretty but this works

```
let templateString = `${y ? `${x} ${y}`: `${x}`}`;
```

i would use the solution from the first comment though.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative, slightly terser approach using nested template literals.

```
`${x}${y ? ` ${y}` : ''}`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use functions inside expressions

Here is an example of it

```js
let x, y;

x = 'test'
y = undefined;

let templateString = `${x} ${y}`;

function fn(value1,value2) { return value2? (value1 + ' ' + value2) : value1 }
console.log('when undefined =',`${fn(x,y)}`);


x = 'test'
y = 'test1';

console.log('when not undefined = ',`${fn(x,y)}`);
```

[reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings)

Comment: Nice, good to know this approach for extract method refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Even better

```
const templateString = `${x} ${y ?? ''}`.trim();
```

Comment: Thank you for this neat solution

Comment: It would be nice, but it doesn't work when `y` is `undefined` as it was requested in the question.

Comment: updated with condition @DavidLeal